# How can I use a detached keyboard with my iPad Pro so I can draw and use quick keys with it flat?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, ipados

How can I use a detached keyboard with my iPad Pro so I can draw and use quick keys with it flat?

I'm left handed so I'd like to put the keyboard on my right and draw with my left-hand, so attaching the keyboard isn't what I'd like at all.  Also if I could use my laptop keyboard and monitor almost like a two monitor setup but while drawing with the ipad pro...

This is probably dead simple, but I'm a newb to drawing on the ipad.

Comment: iPads are fully compatible with most (if not all) standard Bluetooth keyboards. I have an old iPad that I occasionally use with an Apple Bluetooth keyboard and it works fine. and if you have a USB-C to USB-A adapter you could plug any standard USB keyboard into the iPad.

Comment: Does your iPad Pro have lightning or USB port? Either can work with a USB and external display and charge if you don’t want bluetooth keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is get a Bluetooth keyboard and set is close to your iPad. Then go to setting/Bluetooth and connect the keyboard. It should work fine. I got my keyboard from an online shopping service and I paid $19. it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I use a detached keyboard with my iPad Pro so I can draw and use quick keys with it flat?

Virtually any Bluetooth keyboard will work with an iPad

> I'm left handed so I'd like to put the keyboard on my right and draw with my left-hand, so attaching the keyboard isn't what I'd like at all.   Just a quick look at the [accessories page](https://www.apple.com/shop/ipad/ipad-accessories/keyboards) give you a wide range of keyboards - from Apple to 3rd party - that work with your iPad

Rotate the video so the connector is in the location you prefer.  I've used my iPad in both "directions" depending on where I was and how far the charging cable would reach.

> Also if I could use my laptop keyboard and monitor almost like a two monitor setup but while drawing with the ipad pro...

There are a few products that can accomplish this:

- [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com/) ($10USD)
- [Astropad](https://astropad.com/product/standard/) (Starting at $30USD)
- [Luna Display](https://astropad.com/product/lunadisplay/) ($70USD)

Each has their pros/cons - you'll have to evaluate to see which has the workflow that fits you best.  Luna Display is a hardware solution that turns your iPad into a second display for your Mac, but with touch/Pencil capability.